# How to use Spark-BigQuery_connector for existing spark environment ( not with google dataproc)

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery

I working on creating data pipeline, which takes the data from various conventional database and CSV files .It will use pyspark for preprocessing and then writes the result dataframe into BigQuery table.

I have copied the jar file `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.1.jar` to the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder and while creating spark object have specified the same in `spark.jars.packages`.

Please give some suggestions, as all blogs I can find are using DataProc as example.

```
spark = SparkSession. \
        builder. \
        enableHiveSupport(). \
        appName('data_load'). \
        master('yarn'). \
        config('spark.jars.packages','com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.23.1'). \
        getOrCreate()
```

Scala Version = 2.12.15

While writing to big query, I am getting error related to authentication.
BigQuery Connection API is in enabled.

```
df.write.format('bigquery') \
  .option('table',big_table_id) \
  .save()
```

ERROR:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.save.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:286)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:746)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:743)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:742)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient.getTable(BigQueryClient.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.getTable$lzycompute(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:67)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.getTable(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:67)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.exists$lzycompute(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:53)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.exists(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:49)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project212/datasets/NYSE_datasets/tables/NYSE_table?prettyPrint=false
{
  "code" : 403,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason" : "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:428)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:284)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a service account to authenticate outside Dataproc, as described he in [spark-bigquery-connector documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#how-do-i-authenticate-outside-gce--dataproc):

> Use a service account JSON key and `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as
> described
> [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).
>
> Credentials can also be provided explicitly either as a parameter or
> from Spark runtime configuration. It can be passed in as a
> base64-encoded string directly, or a file path that contains the
> credentials (but not both).
>
> Example: `spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentials", "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_IN_BASE64>")`
>
> or
>
> `spark.conf.set("credentials", "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_IN_BASE64>")`
>
> Alternatively, specify the credentials file name.
>
> `spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile","</path/to/key/file>")`
>
> or
>
> `spark.conf.set("credentialsFile","</path/to/key/file>")`
>
> Another alternative to passing the credentials, is to pass the access
> token used for authenticating the API calls to the Google Cloud
> Platform APIs. You can get the access token by running `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`.
>
> `spark.read.format("bigquery").option("gcpAccessToken","<acccess token>")`
>
> or
>
> `spark.conf.set("gcpAccessToken","<access-token>")`